# Correct way to register a parameter for model in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I tried to define a simple model in Pytorch. The model computes negative log prob for a gaussian distribution:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class GaussianModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(GaussianModel, self).__init__()

        self.register_parameter('mean', nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1),
                                                     requires_grad=True))
        
        self.pdf = torch.distributions.Normal(self.state_dict()['mean'],
                                              torch.tensor([1.0]))
    def forward(self, x):
        return -self.pdf.log_prob(x)

model = GaussianModel()
```

Then I tried to optimize the `mean` parameter:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.002)
for _ in range(5):
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  nll = model(torch.tensor([3.0], requires_grad=True))
  nll.backward()
  optimizer.step()
  print('mean : ', model.state_dict()['mean'],
                 ' - Negative Loglikelihood : ', nll.item())
```

But it seems the gradient is zero and `mean` does not change:

```
mean :  tensor([0.])  - Negative Loglikelihood :  5.418938636779785
mean :  tensor([0.])  - Negative Loglikelihood :  5.418938636779785
mean :  tensor([0.])  - Negative Loglikelihood :  5.418938636779785
mean :  tensor([0.])  - Negative Loglikelihood :  5.418938636779785
mean :  tensor([0.])  - Negative Loglikelihood :  5.418938636779785
```

Did I register and use the `mean` parameter correctly? can autograd compute the gradient for `torch.distributions.Normal.log_prob` or I should implement the `backward()` for the model?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're over complicating registering your parameter. You can just assign a new `self.mean` attribute to be an `nn.Parameter` then use it like a tensor for the most part.

`nn.Module` overrides the `__setattr__` method which is called every time you assign a new class attribute. One of the things it does is check to see if you assigned an `nn.Parameter` type, and if so, it adds it to the modules dictionary of registered parameters.

Because of this, the easiest way to register your parameter is as follows:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class GaussianModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GaussianModel, self).__init__()
        self.mean = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1))
        self.pdf = torch.distributions.Normal(self.mean, torch.tensor([1.0]))

    def forward(self, x):
        return -self.pdf.log_prob(x)
```